# Unfollow the post you commented on a separate website using Facebook’s social plugin

Tags: facebook, comments

I commented on an article on TechCrunch and I’m not interested in receiving notifications about the new comments (unless they are on my comment).

There is no 'unfollow post' button, not even on the Facebook notifications popup—notifications popup usually have this little cross on hover to unfollow, but there is none here:

[image]

Does anyone know the solution?